# Removing the circle outline rendered on Box2d CircleShape

Tags: libgdx

How can I remove the outline on the `CircleShape` below?

```
CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
circle.setRadius(1f);
```

This is what I'm using to draw:

```
batch.draw(textureRegion, position.x - 1, position.y - 1, 1f, 1f, 2, 2, 1, 1, angle);
```

I use this to set the body for a Box2d collision but I get a silly circle shape around my texture in `libGdx`. My textured sprite (ball) has a circle over the top of it with a line running from center along the radius.

Any ideas on how to remove the overlying circle lines?

Comment: It sounds like you are using the DebugRenderer?  Can you post your full code?

Comment: Instead of full code, just post the relevant parts.

Comment: Yes using DebugRenderer but thought can use debugDisable somwhere?

Comment: RubberMallet - nice one, was using the demo code example... this was the culprit..
    debugRenderer.render(world, camera.combined);

Comment: @Brett you should mark that as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you are using the DebugRenderer which would cause the outline.